# Variable Used In DataSource C#

Tags: c#, variables, datasource

I have the following code but it seems to not connect, just wondering whether i'm referring to the variable wrong?

```
sqlConnectionNW.ConnectionString = "Data Source=@server;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=True";
```

When I change it to:

```
sqlConnectionNW.ConnectionString = "Data Source=ISSP\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=True";
```

It works fine. It's just when I change it to the variable 'server'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you write something between "" it's recognized as a string, to use a variable you have to write it outside of the ""'s and with a + before it.if some more variable or string is coming behind you must use another + after your variable.

```
"Data Source=" +variblename+ ";Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=True"
```

Answer (score 2):

It would be more like this:

```
string mySQLServer = "ISSP\SQLEXPRESS";

sqlConnectionNW.ConnectionSTring = "Data Source=" + mySQLServer + ";Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=True";
```

Comment: This worked well! Short and simple, just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a variable like that in the connection string. You need to do any replacements before using the connection string.

Comment: Would it be possible to do something like:

String dSource = "Data Source=@server;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=True";

sqlConnectionNW.ConnectionString = dSource;

Comment: That's valid code, but not valid logic. You need to do the replacements before using it, aka `dSource.Replace("@server", "myReplacementValue")`

Answer (score 1):

you could use string.format(), this will allow you to use the variable

```
sqlConnectionNW.ConnectionString = string.format("Data Source={0};Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=True",server)
```

Answer (score 1):

You maybe better off using the SqlConnectionStringBuilder class
[Sql Connection String Builder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dce36088.aspx)

This may allow you to generate the connection string in way more meaningful to you